# Facebook SDK issues with app name mismatch while trying to share via Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm having the hardest time getting the Facebook sdks integrated with my android app.  All I want to do is utilize the sharing feature of the sdk.

I get the following error:

I'm currently have my gradle configured to 
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'

String.xml

```
 <string name="app_name">TestApp</string>
 <string name="facebook_app_id">123456789</string>
```

With in my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mtr_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.test.Application"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">



    <activity
        android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code for sharing:

```
  // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
 FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(_activity)
.setApplicationName("TestApp")
.build();
```

Within the actual Facebook Dashboard:

```
 - Google Play Package Name = com.test
 - Class Name = com.test.MainActivity
 - Display Name = TestApp
 - App ID = 123456789
 - Also added the keyHashes to the keystore that is used to sign the generated apt
```

Note: The TestApp is stated "This app is in development mode" within the Facebook dashboard.

When I run the application, I get the error when it tries to share the information and get the exception:

**`Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.  Please check the application name configured by the dialog.`**

1. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong because the app name
   "TestApp" matches the "Display Name" under the Facebook ->Settings
   -> Display Name "TestApp".  I've verified that the appId is the same as well.
2. Does that Facebook app need to be published and is this why i'm having issue?  I only want to use the sdk so that the native android app can post to Facebook.
3. Is there anything else i'm just not seeing.

I followed the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#maven

Any advice appreciated!
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Try Class Name = MainActivity

Comment: Thanks Toan, but it was the accessibility of the Facebook app settings.  The error message was just really misleading

Comment: Let's create an answer for this issues then accept it :) for another guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I figured it out.  The error message was misleading.  The Facebook app needs to be logged in as a user that is one of the Facebook Roles (Admin, Developer, Test, etc) if the Facebook app is not public yet.

Comment: Is this also true for test users ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey confirm whether you have the same package in the Facebook dashboard as your app package name

http://w3facility.org/question/android-facebook-connectivity-fails/

Comment: Thanks, but it was because the Facebook app wasn't public.  It's weird that the exception message would be so misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a mobile/cordova app, with FB sdk and use the shareDialog of fb.

I had the same error : Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.  Please check the application name configured by the dialog

The weird thing is that it worked in the android emulator and in browser but not on device.

Anyway here is what I found out: as I'm using a test version of my app in facebook developer portal, then the name is something like
"MySuperApp - Test1", and in my app code I was refering to "MySuperApp"

Once I used this name with "- Test1" in my app code then it started to work.

Hope it helps.

Nicolas